# HasMany WhereNotIn

Tags: laravel, has-many, eloquent, where-in

I am creating a query in laravel via models to filter out what is/isnt already in a group.

Models:

- Group
- GroupMembers
- Users

Filters in place:

```
function members()
Groups->hasMany(GroupMembers)
```

Trying to achieve this:

```
Users->whereNotIn(Groups->members())
```

This is the lines of code in question, how the rest of it is all built I believe to be irrelevant:

```
$groups = Groups::find($request['id']);
//        die($groups->members);
    return view('admin.groups.add_member', 
           ['group' => $groups, 
            'users' => User::whereNotIn('id', $groups->members->user)]);
```

the die() command returns the lines of the members successfully. The return statement groups->members returns an array of [1,1,1] (this is the group id where there are 3 members of the group)

I am sure its something simple but some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (assuming the column is called `user_id`):

```
User::whereNotIn('id', $groups->members->pluck('user_id'))->get()
```

Comment: Well thats better than the solution I had literally just written. I forgot all about pluck! `return view('admin.groups.add_member', ['group' => $groups, 'users' => User::whereNotIn('id', $groups->members->pluck('member_id'))->get()]);` The method I used was to create a new function inside the Groups model and copy the original members function and add ->select('member_id') .... same thing really but more code!